# Tensorflow: traning by batch stuck forever in sess.run

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I'm trying to train my model batch by batch, as I couldn't find any example to how to do it properly. This is as far as I can do, on my mission to find how to train a model batch by batch in Tensorflow.

```
queue=tf.FIFOQueue(capacity=50,dtypes=[tf.float32,tf.float32],shapes=[[10],[2]])
enqueue_op=queue.enqueue_many([X,Y])
dequeue_op=queue.dequeue()

qr=tf.train.QueueRunner(queue,[enqueue_op]*2)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    X_train_batch,y_train_batch=tf.train.batch(dequeue_op,batch_size=2)
    coord=tf.train.Coordinator()
    enqueue_threads=qr.create_threads(sess,coord,start=True)
    sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
    for epoch in range(100):
        print("inside loop1")
        for iter in range(5):
            print("inside loop2")
            if coord.should_stop():
                break
            batch_x,batch_y=sess.run([X_train_batch,y_train_batch])
            print("after sess.run")
            print(batch_x.shape)
            _=sess.run(optimizer,feed_dict={x_place:batch_x,y_place:batch_y})
        coord.request_stop()
        coord.join(enqueue_threads)
```

Which outputs,

```
inside loop1
inside loop2
```

As you can see,
Which stuck forever when it runs the `batch_x,batch_y=sess.run([X_train_batch,y_train_batch])` line.
I don't know how could I solve this, or is this the proper way to train a model batch by batch?

Comment: is the output really "inside loop1, inside loop1" or is it  "inside loop1, inside loop2" ?  Secondly, it seems to me that your last two lines are indented just a little too much and should align with the "for epoch" line.

Comment: sorry for the typo,edited now and I found the solution,editing the question now..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After couple hour of searching, I found the Solution myself. So, I'm answering my own question now below.
The queues are filled by background threads, which are created when you call `tf.train.start_queue_runners()` If you don't call this method, the background threads will not start, the queues will remain empty, and the training op will block indefinitely waiting for input.

**FIX:**
call `tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess)` just before the training loop.
Like I did below:

```
queue=tf.FIFOQueue(capacity=50,dtypes=[tf.float32,tf.float32],shapes=[[10],[2]])
enqueue_op=queue.enqueue_many([X,Y])
dequeue_op=queue.dequeue()

qr=tf.train.QueueRunner(queue,[enqueue_op]*2)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    X_train_batch,y_train_batch=tf.train.batch(dequeue_op,batch_size=2)
    coord=tf.train.Coordinator()
    enqueue_threads=qr.create_threads(sess,coord,start=True)
    tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess)
    for epoch in range(100):
        print("inside loop1")
        for iter in range(5):
            print("inside loop2")
            if coord.should_stop():
                break
            batch_x,batch_y=sess.run([X_train_batch,y_train_batch])
            print("after sess.run")
            print(batch_x.shape)
            _=sess.run(optimizer,feed_dict={x_place:batch_x,y_place:batch_y})
        coord.request_stop()
        coord.join(enqueue_threads)
```